# python - returning the type of an object function / method call

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, printing

I solve such a problem and I ran into a problem.

Here is the content of the sentence: *Using the command "type" check the type of the object returned by the function (print) and the method-hello the class Person.*

here is the code I have written so far:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="John", surname="Douglas"):
        self.name= name
        self.surname= surname

        def hello(self):
            print("Hello" + self.name + " " + self.surname)

            Person.hello= "text"
            p = Person()
            p.hello()
```

and I would like to check the type of the object returned by the Hello method of Person class.

using the following command:

```
print (type(p.hello()))
```

however, this command returns nothing - I don't know if it does the job well. I would like to ask for help / advice.

I thank you in advance for every answer!

Comment: Use `p.hello` instead of `p.hello()`. The former is the method itself, while the latter is the result of calling the method (which happens to be `None`)

Comment: @AlexGrounds: It sounds like they're *supposed* to print the type of the return value, rather than the type of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name="John", surname="Douglas"):
        self.name= name
        self.surname= surname

    def hello(self):
        

        #return the string 
        return "Hello " + self.name + " " + self.surname
            
        #Person.hello= "text"
        
#instantiate class Person outside the class
p = Person()
            #p.hello()

print(type(p.hello()))
```

Whatever that you created inside the function and want to access it outside you  must return it

Answer (score 0):

You should have a return value before checking its type, like [SP_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66849905/15365133).
Just want to add that if you're going to check the data type in some if-else clauses, then [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is a better option than comparing its type using `type()`. Like:

```
p = Person()

if isinstance(p, Person):
    print("do something")
```